# Should I use "subembodiments" or still "embodiments"?

Tags: specification

Suppose I have a novel device that requires an A and a B.

I can describe variations of an A, so A1, A2, A3, and with figures. Same for the B variations.

In the detailed spec when describing variations, do I state

> In some **embodiments** of the present disclosure, A1 is ...

or

> In some **subembodiments** of the present disclosure, A1 is ...

? I've only found about 1,800 patents using the latter. For example, "In one affiliated embodiment of the above subembodiment"

Answer (score 1):

The term subembodiment is very uncommon and could lead to objections if the examiner does not understand what it means. Every possible combination of features you want your disclosure to include is an embodiment.

In some jurisdictions like the US, it is generally regarded as a bad idea to use the term embodiment in the description, the embodiments should instead be introduced as "examples". This is at least what I have been told by US colleagues.

Comment: As a retired patent agent I am not aware of problems with “embodiment”. There are concerns with “exemplary embodiment”. The drafter thinks it just means “an example” but the word can also mean an stand-out example. I agree sub-embodiment is very odd and likely to generate unhappy confusion.

Comment: Excellent. That is a solid bit of advice, @GeorgeWhite. I too first thought "exemplary" means "stand out". I'll also stay away from "subembodiment".