# "In some embodiments" or "In one embodiment"?

Tags: specification

As a follow-up to  a previous question [Should I use "subembodiments" or still "embodiments"?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/24988/27911), some patents use the following spec phrase repeatedly

> In one embodiment, ...

while others use the phrase

> In some embodiments, ...

Should I hedge my detailed spec language to always say the plural? Is there ever an advantage to say "in one embodiment"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my opinion only. I prefer "In some embodiments" over "In one embodiment" because when it comes to the support of a claimed specific combination of features, the specification as a whole has to be considered. The term "one" can be construed as "single". This means that if you have a specification that reads:

> In one embodiment, the device further comprises B.
> In one embodiment, the device further comprises C.
> In one embodiment, the device further comprises D.

Do you actually describe the device with the combination B+C, or B+D, or B+C+D? It is difficult to say, but you do not want to be in that spot. One could certainly construe that only one option is valid each time, e.g. the device just with B, or the device with B+C. You cannot know which one will be, which is not good. But in any case, say the first option you go for is accepted, e.g. claim 1 says the device comprises B and C, another combination with the same features may not be accepted because of "one embodiment", i.e. a "single embodiment", hence e.g. claim 2 depending upon claim 1 and further defining that the device comprises D could be added matter because the description does not disclose such embodiment.

Conversely, "some embodiments" at least cannot be construed as being just one particular embodiment. It does not mean that you will not be facing a problem of what combinations you actually disclose in your specification, but you have more arguments to defend the different combinations.

The discussion of disclosed combinations seems far-fetched, but in Europe that is a big issue that appears very often.